# Is nitrous oxide hypergolic with anything reasonably safe and obtainable?

Tags: liquid-fuel, amateur-rocketry, oxidizer, hypergolics, nitrous-oxide

Can I start an amateur rocket using nitrous oxide as either oxidizer or monopropellant, using a hypergolic slug of something reasonable for use by an amateur rocketeer? What substance could it be?

Comment: This is a bit broad and opinion based as "safe" and "obtainable" are subjective. I'd suggest defining some parameters

Comment: I would suggest reading 'Ignition' if you have not already done so. It covers many fuels and their safety (but not their obtainability by the general public).

Comment: GdD: Is there a wide range of even remotely safe and remotely obtainable substances that fit the bill?

Comment: @OrangePeel52: I checked Ignition! before posting this question. No hypergolics were mentioned in use with $N_2O$ and the substance only appeared as two scarce mentions, one for early experimental rocketry as monopropellant or hybrid motor oxidizer (no ignition mechanism mentioned) and one as temperature depressant with $N_2O_4$ (failed).

Comment: Triethylaluminium is the best i have so far, and surely does not meet safety limits. https://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijae/2014/269836/

Comment: Another option, but im not sure how to determine availability.  "When passed over a warm ruthenium catalyst bed, gaseous nitrous oxide and an ethylene-ethane gaseous blend combust instantly"  https://sbir.nasa.gov/SBIR/abstracts/15/sbir/phase1/SBIR-15-1-S3.02-9159.html

Comment: Ethylene and ethane are ordinary flammable gases and should be reasonably obtainable from commercial gas suppliers. Ruthenium catalyst might be harder -- the real question is whether this actually works *well*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://sbir.nasa.gov/SBIR/abstracts/15/sbir/phase1/SBIR-15-1-S3.02-9159.html) is a mix that apparently could work.

"When passed over a warm ruthenium catalyst bed, gaseous nitrous oxide and an ethylene-ethane gaseous blend combust instantly"

Supplies could be found for the following:[Ruthenium](https://www.etsy.com/listing/400869491/ruthenium-metal-9995-pure-element-44-ru?utm_campaign=shopping_us_ChemistryCabinet_sfc_osa&utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=google&utm_custom1=0&utm_content=11632179&gclid=CjwKEAiAuc_FBRD7_JCM3NSY92wSJABbVoxB_s32nISkNFI29jfRIHeJWjzs_ZTHFlij0njcpp6EXBoCi87w_wcB) and [Ethane](https://www.shopcross.com/gas/ethane-c2h6-calibration-gas/sku/103L-152N-50?gclid=CjwKEAiAuc_FBRD7_JCM3NSY92wSJABbVoxBJLo8YNj5F8BA2KuuHqoXIfacPioC7wIhZ9J46Ba8WhoChvbw_wcB)

But I could not find sources for Ethylene, but it seems to be available for industrial uses. This could disqualify this combination depending on the meaning of 'available'.

The safety sheets for [ethane](http://www.inchem.org/documents/icsc/icsc/eics0266.htm) and [ethylene](http://www.inchem.org/documents/icsc/icsc/eics0475.htm) list only that the gases are very flammable, but unlike Triethylaluminium will not combust on contact with air... so thats a step up.

The safety data for [ruthenium](https://www.caymanchem.com/msdss/14339m.pdf) seems to list is as quite poisonous, so that could disqualify this combination depending on the meaning of 'safe'.

Comment: Thanks. One serious problem: how would one go about making a hypergolic slug out of ethane and ethylene?

Comment: I agree that could be challenging, I have stuck to answering the title question because i dont know much about how rockets are plumbed.

Comment: A hypergolic slug is a small piece of solid (may be a swab of cloth/cotton/paper coated in liquid) placed in the combustion chamber. Upon contact with the propellant/oxidizer it combusts spontaneously, initiating combustion with actual fuel - essentially, it's a chemical ignitor. It's pretty safe even when using pretty nasty hypergols because of the minuscule amounts used. Ethane and ethylene are gases in room temperature though.

Comment: Rather than a slug, it might make more sense to use a torch igniter -- something like a tiny welding torch / rocket chamber that fires into the combustion chamber. Obviously this means more plumbing and valves, but is better for restarts.

Comment: Also the ruthenium you linked is a compound, not the metal itself which is probably safer.

Answer (score 2):

Most if not all hypergolic fuels are toxic to varying degrees. Hydrazine, mono-
methyl hydrazine, and unsymmetrical dimethyl hydrazine are all in this category. Virgin Galactic Space Ship One used nitrous oxide with aluminum grain but needed an igniter. A venting problem on Apollo-Soyuz return knocked out one astronaut and all three had to be hospitalized for a time. I would avoid hypergolic fuels. They are not for the amateur rocketeer.

Comment: As long as it's poisonous through ingestion, and not e.g. through skin contact, or inhalation, that's not such a big problem. Also, recognize the difference between hypergolic fuel and hypergolic slug.

Comment: If there was a reasonable hypergolic chemical that was only toxic from ingestion, don't you believe that NASA or Space X would be using it ?

Comment: With nitrous oxide? 150s of specific impulse as monoprop; 1 mole of $O_2$ for two moles of $N_2$ as oxidizer? Absolutely not. No matter how friendly and safe the hypergol, it doesn't make up for lousy performance of the oxidizer.

Comment: This isn't really an answer, as some hypergols are clearly more dangerous than others and exotic possibilities haven't necessarily been exhausted when hydrazine/nitrogen tetroxide works reasonably welll.

Answer (score 2):

My advice is to synthesize some Chromyl Chloride from a oxidized salt of Chromium as it is hypergolic with methanol and sulfur. You can also get about a liter of the liquid with just a days work and it isn’t too toxic to handle. Sadly I couldn’t find a reliable propellant mix using n2o.