# Hypergolic slugs with gaseous reactants

Tags: fuel, engine-design, hypergolics

Based on points raised in [this](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/20392/is-nitrous-oxide-hypergolic-with-anything-reasonably-safe-and-obtainable) question about hypergolic slugs.

My understanding of a hypergolic slug is that it is a solid or a liquid on a paper patch placed in the combustion chamber and it will spontaneously combust on contact with the fuel.

Can a gaseous hypergol be used as a starter? If so, how?

Comment: One simple approach I know is to use solid or liquid substrates that react producing the gaseous hypergol. But I don't think there are any room temperature reactions producing ethylene and ethane